# java.lang.StackOverflowError while parsing a json string with org.json.JSONObject

Tags: java, stack-overflow, json

When i try to convert a json string to a JSONObject, i got the following error.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:116)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:322)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:116)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:322)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:116)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:322)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:116)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:322)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:116)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:322)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:116)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:322)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:116)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:322)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:116)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:322)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:116)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:322)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:116)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:322)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:116)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:322)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:116)
```

My code sample:

```
String jsonStr = "{\"node\":[";
JSONObject obj =  new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

Then i found that, the error occurred due to the broken json string ***"{"node":["*** was used.

My question is,

Is this an issue? If so how do i fix this issue?

What is the impact of this issue?

Comment: It certainly looks like a bug in the org.json package; this JSON is outright illegal to begin with and should be reported as such

Comment: try this 
`String jsonStr = '{"node":"[....]"}';
JSONObject obj =  new JSONObject(jsonStr);`

Comment: @HimanshuChaudhary , yes i got the reason for that issue but i'm curious to know that how to fix it & what is the impact of the issue.

Comment: @Selvakumar Hi, what is the org.json package you're using?